# Issue getting back value from a ID, Class Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue getting a value from an ID or a Class in just Safari when I put back the value from this class it just gives me a **"\n"** new line in Safari but brings back the value in all other browsers.

```
<span class="Calculator_device_retail_price" id="Calculator_device_retail_price">
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalDeviceRetailCost") %>
</span>
```

```
deviceRetailCost = $(this).find('.Calculator_device_retail_price').text();
deviceRetailCostfromid = $(this).find('#Calculator_device_retail_price').text();
deviceRetailCostfromhtml = $(this).find('.Calculator_device_retail_price').html();
console.log("deviceRetailCost when adding a device " + deviceRetailCost);
console.log("deviceRetailCostfromid when adding a device " + deviceRetailCostfromid);
console.log("deviceRetailCostfromhtml when adding a device " + deviceRetailCostfromhtml);
```

Comment: What's `$(this)`? Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: Has nothing to do with css.

Comment: $(".Calculator_device").on("click", function () { this = .Calculator_device

Answer (score 0):

The issue in Safari was that it didn't understand the line break and returned the **"/n"** tag instead of the value in the span class.

When I changed the code to this it worked:

```
<span class="Calculator_device_retail_price" id="Calculator_device_retail_price"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalDeviceRetailCost")%></span>
```